# Finding an integrating factor $w$ for $\sigma$ such that $dw = \sigma$?

Tags: differential-geometry, integrating-factor

Suppose $\sigma = (yz + x^2z^2 + 3xy^2z)dx dy dz$ then how do we find a 2 - form $w$ such that $dw = \sigma$?.

As I know that if it would have been $\sigma = \sum_{i} \alpha_{i} dx_{i}$ then as a Pffafian form an integrating factor would exist iff $(X).\nabla \times X = 0$ where $X = (\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},....,\alpha_{n})$.

But here $\sigma$ is a 3-form and we have to find a 2 form $w$ such that when exterior derivative $d$ is applied to $w$ then it will result into a 3-form $\sigma$.

Also, any reference which has problems on integrating factors, forms similar to above ones?

Comment: Writing $\omega = f \, dx \wedge dy + g \, dx \wedge dz + h \, dy \wedge dz$, then I think $d \omega = (f_z - g_y + h_x) \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$. Eyeballing it, it looks like $f = \frac{3}{2} x y^2 z^2, g = - x^2 y z^2$, and $h = xyz$ works, right?

Comment: Oh yes!, but we get $(-f_{z} + g_{x} - h_{y}) = (yz + x^2 z^2 + 3 x y^2 z)$, so I think we have 9 solutions for $w$!

Comment: sorry 6 solutions  for $w$!